# Spring Batch - Recovery after Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch Job with a `ItemProcessor` that can possibly fail with an Exception. If that happens I have an `ItemProcessListener` in place that handles the recovery (marking the item as failed so that it would not be picked up in the next run).

That solution works like a charm with 'regular' exceptions, however I've experienced a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error recently where `onProcessError()` is not called and the item will not be excluded in the next run.

I noticed however that `JobExecutionListener.afterJob()` is called where I could get the job parameters of the failed execution and query *all* items of that execution again and mark them as failed.

Is there a better approach to my problem?

Comment: can you post some code .that would be great ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `onProcessError` is ill-named. It only listens for `Exception`s, not for `Error`s. Java strongly discourages handling `Error`s via catch-blocks. The reason is, that the jvm signals a fault which is not in the programming but in the configuration of the vm via an `Error`. They should be taken as a strong indicator, your vm-setup needs correction.

In your case, you write about an `OutOfMemoryError` which occurs if your memory demand is higher than the memory, which has been assigned to the Java-job via -Xmx/Xms startparameters. You either assign to little memory or you consume too much of it. This should be fixed, not caught via some technical trick.

First of all, you should find out what causes this error. Maybe you simply need to assign more memory, probably some of your algorithms are too greedy in memory consumption and not unlikely, you have a memory leak as a root cause.

Comment: We went with an additional step that removes all 'hanging' items after a defined period as a solution to our problem. We know exactly what causes our problem but it is unresolvable by the restrictions we have. It would have been nice if we were able to at least log some info in `ItemProcessListener.onProcessError()`. It is somewhat inconsistent in that in `AbstractJob.execute()` any `Throwable` is catched, and the exit status of the execution is updated and saved considering the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: @user1099501 : You should consider two further options. Java allows to specify arbitrary OS-commands in case of an oome by using the `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` option (e.g. kill the vm alltogether). You can also take a look at special references `SoftReference` or `WeakReference`, which allow some special handling when it comes to garbage-collection.